# Confused converting XML form one format to an other

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I need to convert messages data from one format to another. The original file have 3472 entries (sms /sms). id, threadId, person won't be needed anymore. But I have to create @time, @name.

The format I have:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<smsall>
  <sms>
    <id>200</id>
    <threadId>65</threadId>
    <address>+123456789</address>
    <person>1</person>
    <date>1387977340608</date>
    <body> This is a text </body>
    <type>1</type>
    <read>1</read>
  </sms>
</smsall>
```

The format I need after running XSLT 1.0:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<allsms count="1">
  <sms address="+123456789" time="" date="1387977340608" type="1" body="This is a text" read="1" service_center="" name="" />
</allsms>
```

I spent many days but I fail miserably. Please can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you also add your XSLT to date, and describe what your issues are?

Comment: Believe me if I wasn’t embarrassed I would post my “best” try. I try to convert the output from an android backup program to another that I can use. The problem is that I am no expert by any means. I am a student and my level obviously isn’t high enough. I am trying based general information and examples (like some I found here) to make an XSL . Whatever I run to online-toolz.com either dose not transfer the Text either does not create attributes with the right order. michael.hor257k’s example that is the most similar to my problem is running perfectly. So it is not the tools problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not very complicated, but you have to remember about two details:

First: The syntax for `xsl:attribute` in **XSLT 1.0** does not allow `select` attribute. Instead you have to use the **content** of this tag, e.g.:

```
 <xsl:attribute name="address">
   <xsl:value-of select="address"/>
 </xsl:attribute>
```

And the second: To have an attribute with an **empty** content, it is enough to
put `xsl:attribute` with *name* only, but without any content, e.g.:

```
<xsl:attribute name="time"/>
```

So the script can look like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="smsall">
    <allsms>
      <xsl:attribute name="count">
        <xsl:value-of select="count(sms)"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </allsms>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="sms">
    <sms>
      <xsl:attribute name="address">
        <xsl:value-of select="address"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="time"/>
      <xsl:attribute name="date">
        <xsl:value-of select="date"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="type">
        <xsl:value-of select="type"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="body">
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(body)"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="read">
        <xsl:value-of select="read"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="service_center"/>
      <xsl:attribute name="name"/>
    </sms>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

For a working example (in **XSLT 1.0**) see http://xsltransform.net/nb9MWsZ

Comment: THANK YOU!!! You don’t understand how many hours I threw away for this! First mistake was that for example “time” and “date” adding them as text time="{@time}" date="{@date}". A second BUG I found to my data was that for some stupid reason the original program ‘ translate it as &frasl; and code didn’t gave me any results. 

Again thank you very much!

Comment: For all those that have devised and download android – Super Backup & Restore : All instead of Super Backup this will fix your data so super backup can restore them. Just keep in mind that you have to replace “&frasl;” to “ ’ ”.

Thank you Valdi_Bo!